# zsh: no matches found - trying to install pydantic[email]

Tags: python, zsh, pydantic, python-venv

After activating my venv and installing Pydantic through

```bash
pip install pydantic
```

I tried creating a new file as follows:

```py
from pydantic import Basemodel, EmailStr

class Person(BaseModel):
      id: int
      name: str
      email: EmailStr
```

and was just running this file with the unused class. But it returned the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validator'
.
.
.
ImportError: email-validator is not installed, run `pip install pydantic[email]`
```

When running the hint

```bash
pip install pydantic[email]
```

it tells me:

```
zsh: no matches found: pydantic[email]
```

Could someone help me with this stupid beginner error? Thanks!

I reinstalled Pydantic, recreated a venv, reactivated the venv.

Comment: sorry not your fault but people have already encountered this pip-on-zsh issue before so looks like a duplicate.  hopefully that fixed your issue though.  welcome aboard.

Answer (score 19):

This has nothing to do with Python, Pydantic, or your virtual environment. It tells you that this is a **shell** error by starting the error message with your shell's name `zsh`.

When you write `... pydantic[email]`, zsh interprets this as a glob pattern to match files named `pydantic` followed by either `e`, `m`, `a`, `i`, or `l`. It finds no files matching that pattern in your working directory and gives you that error.

To avoid this, you can simply put that argument in quotes like this:

```bash
pip install 'pydantic[email]'
```

Comment: Thanks @daniil for the explanation. this makes absolutely sense

Comment: pip install email-validator